# How to convert BatchNorm weight of caffe to pytorch BathNorm?

Tags: caffe, pytorch, pycaffe

BathNorm and Scale weight of caffe model can be read from pycaffe, which are three weights in BatchNorm and two weights in Scale. I tried to copy those weights to pytorch BatchNorm with codes like this:

```
if 'conv3_final_bn' == name:
    assert len(blobs) == 3, '{} layer blob count: {}'.format(name, len(blobs))
    torch_mod['conv3_final_bn.running_mean'] = blobs[0].data
    torch_mod['conv3_final_bn.running_var'] = blobs[1].data
elif 'conv3_final_scale' == name:
    assert len(blobs) == 2, '{} layer blob count: {}'.format(name, len(blobs))
    torch_mod['conv3_final_bn.weight'] = blobs[0].data
    torch_mod['conv3_final_bn.bias'] = blobs[1].data
```

The two BatchNorm acts differently. I also tried to set conv3_final_bn.weight=1 and conv3_final_bn.bias=0 to verify the BN layer of caffe, the results didn't match either.

How should I deal with the wrong matching?

Answer (score 2):

Got it! There is still a third parameter in BatchNorm of caffe. Codes should be:

```
if 'conv3_final_bn' == name:
    assert len(blobs) == 3, '{} layer blob count: {}'.format(name, len(blobs))
    torch_mod['conv3_final_bn.running_mean'] = blobs[0].data / blobs[2].data[0]
    torch_mod['conv3_final_bn.running_var'] = blobs[1].data / blobs[2].data[0]
elif 'conv3_final_scale' == name:
    assert len(blobs) == 2, '{} layer blob count: {}'.format(name, len(blobs))
    torch_mod['conv3_final_bn.weight'] = blobs[0].data
    torch_mod['conv3_final_bn.bias'] = blobs[1].data
```

Comment: I am trying to transfer a trained network from caffe to pytorch, your solution does not make same results.

Comment: NVM. I forgot to call model.eval(), so that it does not used the running mean and running var.